# Can I connect two Mac Pro to one monitor?

Tags: mac, mac-pro, thunderbolt-display

I am using an apple thunderbolt display and two mac pro's.  I would like to connect the two processors to the one display.  is this possible?

Comment: It is common to connect multiple computers to a single keyboard, video display and mouse, this is called a KVM switch. There are mini displayport KVM switches which are (generally) compatible with a Thunderbolt port. Try searching for "thunderbolt kvm" and look for one that is Mac compatible. That should likely do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot physically connect both Mac Pro's to the same Apple Thunderbolt Display. However, you might look in to a KVM switch which lets one display connect to multiple computers.

However, you could connect one Mac Pro to the display, and use Remote Desktop software on that Mac Pro to display the screen from the other Mac Pro.

Comment: @David No problem. Please mark the question as answered if you got the feedback you wanted.